# Find a specific line of text in a text document and insert the next 37 lines of text into a database

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, text

Helo,
     I have an SQL database, and 50 text files, and Visual Basic 2010 Premimum,
I need to find a specific line of text in the text files and then take the next 37 lines of text and save them in my database. I need advice as to point me in the right direction. Also if anyone might know of a book I can use for future reference it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Const textToFind As String = "a specific line of text"
Const maxLineCount As Int32 = 37
Dim allLines As New List(Of String)
Dim path As String = "c:\temp\MyTest.txt"

Try
   If File.Exists(path) Then
      File.Delete(path)
   End If

   Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path)
   For i As Int32 = 1 To 100
      sw.WriteLine("This")
      sw.WriteLine("is some text")
       sw.WriteLine("to test")
       sw.WriteLine("Reading")
       sw.WriteLine("a specific line of text")
   Next
   sw.Close()

   Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(path)
   Dim lineCounter As Int32 = 0
   Dim lineFound As Int32 = -1
   Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
      Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine
      If lineFound = -1 Then
         If line.Equals(textToFind) Then
            lineFound = 0
         End If
      Else
         lineCounter += 1
         If lineCounter <= maxLineCount Then
            allLines.Add(line)
         Else
            Exit Do
         End If
      End If
   Loop
   sr.Close()
   ' save found lines to the database '
Catch ex As Exception
   Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", ex.ToString())
End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

As for parsing the file, it's easy to [search files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) line-by-line:

```
Var i = 0
Var foundOnLineNumber = -1
For Each line In File.ReadAllLines("<file name here>")
    i = i + 1
    If foundOnLineNumber > 0 Then
        ' Add line to database
    Else If <criteria for finding "that" line> Then
        foundOnLineNumber = i
    End If
Next
```

I've never been good at VB (I usually do C#, so this might not compile). Try to figure out what criteria you are looking for and replace that in the code above. [Here](http://www.amazon.com/My-Favorite-VB-NET-Books/lm/226RLNT3LYZ3U) is a list of VB.NET books. Find one that covers ADO or some other database access technology. I think your biggest help will be to simply get a good grasp on the VB language and the facilities that .NET has at its disposal.